# Combine scriptaculous.js and validationEngine.jquery

Tags: prototypejs, scriptaculous, jquery-validation-engine

I would like to combine the two JavaScript libraries/frameworks/scripts scriptaculous.js and validationEngine.jquery but I don’t have a clue how to do it.

My code is like this:

```
<head>
...

// auto complete            
<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


// validation
<script type="text/javascript" src="query-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validationEngine-de.js"></script>

// auto complete
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    new Ajax.Autocompleter('architect', 'suggestion', ‚'ArchitectQuery.php', {minChars: 3});
    });
</script>

// validation
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form-validation").validationEngine();
   });
</script>


...
</head>


<body>
...
<input type="text" name="architect" size="45" maxlength="100" id="architect" data-validation-engine="validate[required, minSize[3]]"  />
<div id="suggestion"></div>
...
</body>
```

I guess I have to somehow add the ‚Event.observe‘ part to the validationEngine - but how?

Thanks
Kashuda

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to use `$.noConflict();`, because prototypejs use also $.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $.noConflict();
 jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#form-validation").validationEngine();
});
```

Domus71